# Change the column name in an ABAP report

Tags: abap

I'm trying to change a name of a column using `cl_salv_table`.

So far I have:

```
  cl_salv_table=>factory(
    IMPORTING
      r_salv_table = o_alv
    CHANGING
      t_table      = t_talv ).

  gr_column = gr_columns->get_column( columnname = 'EBELP' ). " <=== SHORT DUMP
  gr_column->set_long_text( value = 'TESTE' ).

  lo_alv_toolbar = o_alv->get_functions( ).
  CALL METHOD lo_alv_toolbar->set_all
    EXPORTING
      value = if_salv_c_bool_sap=>true.

  o_alv->display( ).
```

But when I run the program I always get a dump:

> Access using a 'ZERO' object reference is not possible.

Can somebody help me please? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one!

```
DATA : cl_columns TYPE REF TO cl_salv_columns,
       cl_column  TYPE REF TO cl_salv_column.

cl_columns = o_alv->get_columns( ).
cl_column = cl_columns->get_column( |EBELP| ).
cl_column->set_long_text( |TESTE| ).
```

Regards, 
Doobidoo

Comment: As a clarification, David's code dumped because he hadn't set `gr_columns` before using it. Hence the "ZERO object reference" error message.

Comment: Thanks Doobidoo that worked just fine, the problem was indeed in what Legxis just mentioned it, so one more time thanks to both!